# What does it mean to have "groups" and "levels" of variables?

Tags: categorical-data, definition

Using [this](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/whatstat/) website, a user can find a correct statistical test for their project.

However, what do they mean when they write "2+ groups" or "2+ levels"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that list, *2+ levels* refers to non-binary categorical "independent" variables. For instance, marital status as 1: single, never married / 2: married or living with partner / 3: widowed or divorced. *Group* refers to the study design, whether the data are independent or paired. As a reminder, a paired design might be a pre/post type of study or a monozygotic twin design. Like the disclaimer at the top of the webpage, those terms are not hard, fast, or universally agreed upon, and they are certainly not a comprehensive way of looking at study designs. Note for instance, unlike your question, they never actually say 2+ groups, because the "off the shelf" methods for independent or paired designs are the most accessible. But there are in fact models for data where you can have more than 2 in a group, and where the correlation between units in the group is separate and imbalanced (like family studies, or studies of monozygotic and dizygotic twins)